# How to ensure that all files were successfully zipped while using the zip() in python,is there any function to check or acknowledge?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i zipped all the files using shutil .make_archive("arch", "zip", path) and  want know whether all the files are zipped.I used the below code to zip the files.

```
shutil.make_archive("arch", "zip", r"path")
```

Comment: Typically, when an operation like this fails, it signals this by raising an exception. Conversely, if no exception was raised, you can typically assume that the operation succeeded. It seems likely that `make_archive` behaves this way unless you've personally seen the method fail to zip all files and not raise an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as pointed out by Kevin/others, in Python (and as most languages with "exception handling") you can expect that most routines will raise/throw an exception on error conditions

if you care about the details, the relevant Python source is in [shutil](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/shutil.py#L679) and [zipfile](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/zipfile.py) where you can see that they use appropriate "context managers" and `raise` exceptions as appropriate, but mostly rely on lower level file operations to throw

if you want some human output to monitor progress, you can use the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) infrastructure, e.g.:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=0)

shutil.make_archive("arch", "zip", "path", logger=logging)
```

(see the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) for more details) will cause it to give more output

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why would you want to do that ? If make_archive did not raises any exceptions, all files in `path` are supposed to be in `arch`.

If you want to know it anyway, you can either :

- unzip the archive with [shutil.unpack_archive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.unpack_archive)
- use [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) to read the archive like this :

  from ZipFile import ZipFile

  with ZipFile("arch.zip") as myzip:
      print(myzip.namelist())

Answer (score -1):

Example 3 at [this link](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89191/shutil.make_archive) seems to indicate that `shutil.make_archive` returns a string with the path and file name of the file that was created. It shows that string being used to check the newly created archive.